# accessing robot via Serial port

Tags: c, macos, serial-port

I have try to access robot via serial port using gcc (i using mac).

I have made my program to send simple command:

> HOME (enter) and there are some feedback from the robot: THIS IS THE
>   HOMING SEQUENCE COMMAND. THE ROBOT WILL SEEK ITS HOMING SWITCHES ON
>   EACH AXIS AND WILL EXECUTE THE HOMING FUNCTION AT THAT LOCATION. DO
>   YOU WANT TO PROCEED (Y/N) ?

and I send

> Y(enter)

and the robot suppose move.

To access robot now is using modem/terminal Zterm.
This modem use baudrate 38400, 8N1

I use the same baudrate and 8n1

This is my code, I do not know what is wrong why my code cannot make the robot move

Thank you

Daniel

```
    #include<stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>  /* String function definitions */
    #include<unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
    #include<fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
    #include<errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
    #include<termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
    //#include<conio.h> 

    /*
     * 'open_port()' - Open serial port 1.
     *
     * Returns the file descriptor on success or -1 on error.
     */

    int buf_size;
    char *buf;
    char *buff;
    int fd; /* File descriptor for the port */

    int open_port(void)
    {

       fd = open("/dev/tty.USA28X1a2P2.2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);  //      USA28X1a2P2.for keyspan 
    //fd = open("/dev/ttys000", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);   
    if (fd == -1) {
     /*
      * Could not open the port.
      */
      perror("cannot open");
   }
     else 
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
        struct termios options;
          /* 
           * Get the current options for the port...
           */
          tcgetattr(fd, &options);

          /*
           * Set the baud rates to 38400...
           */

         cfsetispeed(&options, B38400);
         cfsetospeed(&options, B38400);


         /*
          * Enable the receiver and set local mode...
          */

         options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

         /*
          * Set the new options for the port...
          */

         tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

         options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */

         options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
         options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
         options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
         options.c_cflag |= CS8;

     return (fd);
    }

    int main(int argc, char**argv) {
        buf =malloc(20);
        buff=malloc(20);

    //   strcpy(buf,"HOME");
    //    strcpy(buff,"Y");
        open_port();
        printf("type the command using Capital Letter : \n");
        scanf("%s",buf);
        write(fd, buf,20); // 
        write(fd," \r ",5);
        printf("Command = %s\n", buf);
        read(fd, buff,50);
        printf(" %s \n",buff);
        free(buf);
        free(buff);
        printf("type Y/N : \n");
        scanf("%s",buf);
        write(fd, buf,2);
        write(fd,"\r",2);

    //    free(buf);
    //  free (buff);
    //    printf("type Y/N : \n");
    //    write(fd, buf,20);
    //    printf("You choose %s \n",buff);
    //    free(buf);

        close(fd);
    }
```

Comment: Please use whitespaces to make your code readable, else you'll get "TL;DR" comments (like this one).

Comment: i such love a case when you got the names like a `buf` and `buff`

Comment: Are you sure that you config your serial port cirrectly. Maybe your robot has some test output via serial when it powered on?

Comment: You check for errors in only a few places, but not for all system calls. You also continue as if nothing happened even where you check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading too much at a time. You allocate your buffers as 20 bytes, `buff=malloc(20);` But here you read 50, `read(fd, buff,50);` That can lead to odd behavior at best. Make sure you allocate as much space as you'll use. You don't even need to allocate it, you can use an array.

```
char buf[1024];
char buff[1024];
```

Then you free your memory before using them again.

```
 free(buf);
 free(buff);
 printf("type Y/N : \n");
 scanf("%s",buf);
```

Don't free buf or buff until after you call `close(fd)`.

Read up on good C style, too. You're doing a few things that aren't bugs, but will make your life harder later.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many errors in the code (like buffer overruns, etc.), but the most obvious one I could spot is here:

```
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */

options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
```

You're setting the fields of the `options` structure **only after you already used it for setting up the file descriptor's properties.** You have to put the call to `tcsetattr()` to the end of this whole sequence:

```
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; /* Mask the character size bits */
options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;

tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
```

If you don't want to mess with manually setting all this yourself, try my [helper function.](http://github.com/H2CO3/serialtool)